# Недопустимый аргумент шаблона, требуется константное выражение времени компиляции

Tags: c++, c++17, константа, constexpr

Есть следующая структура классов:

RCC.h

```
#pragma once

template<auto address>
class Register
{
public:

    static void Set(unsigned int value)
    {
        *reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(address) = value;
    }
};

 template<auto address>
 class RCCBase
 {
 private:

     static constexpr auto cr_address = address + 0x00;
     static constexpr auto pllcfgr_address = address + 0x04;

 public:

     struct CR : public Register<cr_address>
     {
     };

     struct PLLCFGR : public Register<pllcfgr_address>
     {
     };

 };

// Только для vs. В IAR подставить конкретный адрес.
extern unsigned int ext_rcc[128];

using RCC = RCCBase<ext_rcc>;
```

И следующий код:

main.cpp

```
#include "RCC.h"

// Только для vs
u32 ext_rcc[128] = { 0 };

int main(void)
{
    RCC::CR::Set(0);
    RCC::PLLCFGR::Set(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Проблема что первая строчка RCC::CR::Set(0); выполняется как положено, а следующая при компиляции создает ошибку:
Ошибка  C2975   address_: недопустимый аргумент шаблона для "Register", требуется константное выражение времени компиляции

Не понимаю, почему в классе RCCBase cr_address остается константой времени компиляции, pllcfgr_address из-за сложения перестает ею быть. Пробовал такое:

```
static constexpr auto offset = 0x04;
static constexpr auto pllcfgr_address = address + offset;
```

Та же самая ошибка. В чем дело-то?

Проект собран как консольное приложение в VS2019 со стандартом C++17

Лог сборки:

```
Сборка начата…
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: ConsoleApplication2, Конфигурация: Debug x64 ------
1>main.cpp
1>C:\Users\fedorov_dn\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\RCC.h(29): error C2975: address: недопустимый аргумент шаблона для "Register", требуется константное выражение времени компиляции
1>C:\Users\fedorov_dn\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\RCC.h(3): message : см. объявление "address"
1>C:\Users\fedorov_dn\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\main.cpp(9): message : выполняется компиляция ссылки на экземпляр класс шаблон функции "RCCBase<& ext_rcc>::PLLCFGR"
1>Сборка проекта "ConsoleApplication2.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Comment: *"В чем дело-то?"* - в том, что не приведен [mcve]

Comment: Согласен, класс Register нужен более подробно

Comment: Угу, а вот разделение на файлы - скорее всего нет. И лог сборки имеет смыл приводить полностью как есть, и указывать чем собрано и с какими параметрами.

Comment: Вопрос обновлен

Comment: Пример может быть сокращен раз в десять. Убирайте все, что не относится к проблеме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
template<auto x_address>
struct Foo {};

char bar[8]{};
Foo<bar + 0> a{};
Foo<bar + 4> b{};
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrS7bSV9ABk8tTADlnACNMYhAANlIAB1QhQnNaO0cXN2jY%2BLofP0CnELDI40xTBIYCZmICJOdXTndC4rpS8oIsgODQiKMyiqqU2q7m1py8iIBKI1QHYmQOKQJMJyjVec0AZhtmByIAanEAfWZ0dGJMISE17E0ZAEEhAmIHU22AMVRUbc0Adn1PgBE1/Q3K7XZAIcrbILlTQAVl0AA4Yf9VoDrq9UGsbJDiB89NsZBdtswvj8kSi0RisTjdNtuASgsSvqTgVJxqxpND5K5ZPJUNIbAYDNshJNppgcatOPICNI5KNxgBrEDaaEqaTcTkynnSeRCEAyUjS7njOCwGCIFCoRZ4dhkCgQNBWm0gYCcV18a3zYi6iBBTWkIK%2BcoAT2kktIDqcVgIAHlaKwQ9zSFgnGpgOw/fgTsUAG6nP2YcRFLazMO%2BeZsxOsPBBYjBuxYP33PBOUMsvh0RgsdM8duCEQSP1KTgqVMoAV6FTV3WQcaoKJmOi6qQAWmXd3Qa1%2BWj0Bk4nx1mBMC9cEE8vRqHmsQ3aYWHMTix/PynvGVo19yHWH9WPTR69mqyjfiU3QtL4bQfreAx/skF53IMYHDJ%2B4zClMMxcKy7IaomvJSOIcLhMu4TcNswDIMg2yugAdJw2wQLghAkOKw7bHYjqhExowseOuhSpqcqkIq0L6hW6qkC2QmkFycikDhOp6gafGkCa5qTAQURbOQlAOlE1qfh4%2BBEJB/CdmwHA9sZwhiJIiYAO61lErYYVIHKSX6OHRls6kENsqBULs%2BGEcRpHkVRNEQKxOk2hxvFGuMCCYIcHQQE5onifqUlalIcn6oasoKkqKoVqsWHSbJClGkpZrKRASDabptpaZakUdMgqjqLUMj6lQHqhN6vqJgGtDBq24aWpG9CxvGGYLKm6aJpmRRmLmS7SQWRbzCNZaHn6VY1nWGCzNJTYtlIkrjMZTCmVwvAWf21nSUo7htRo3GTkE07JTJ84JEuq7rpu276Hoe4HkeCSWNYT7Dp474jHe6SPv%2BfRpA%2BCSw3pQGNCBUNGIei3AfB2Q3oB2NI7BIHo7eyEimhnBOS5GUydIeEEUR2ytamFHaJRMg87R9GGUxpAsU19XitonH8juegxXlAkgKsqyUYrKuq2rqpSKlIASYzZW6jlinVUgqleZp9qi067iYAZJDKBdXZmTdHaWQOtn2Y5GsM250geWpWw%2BX5LOBezz1czzfPhRb7E6KsEuyyycUJVgYSfSJ8hpa52HakY8m5Qn8vaAAnJR0LhIXsefJ8EoyIX2jcNwqwa8VmeldnefGlVVW1VHDXm2xYTZsgURRHs2acIXexF3sABqDCcOEeycDIeziER7qsJ6fV%2BoNw2nfIEZRpNCbScms2HfIC05nmiZrcgxabfQ22VtWtbEEG9bnwaxDNh79tXeZzs7qDgViOdQY5paGF2h9Wc31FzSAAPTrnAUDXQe5tjwKiKEJweAzh4FzMudB%2BBmDAFoLEMwyBdQsBOAQUG%2BMLCnkhmTZQMMELE3hqjOgOMXzHkpoBPGDRaC/kqEwr8/CfwU1YRBEmzQcZwQqLwumExUJmXpiVTKq9iJOCEIPbYY9i5F22LPee1EZD8xttiGOzEIpixjqsSW3F478UVMqDWWsdbeyyjnA2FUjYgBNhpO0dUnSN2tgxIyHZLrdidn2Kyfo7LMAcnvVRLdMq%2By8gHXYbMtE6L0ZRAxRjwgmNotYqKtjRiOMTolFOKV07a3Sh47K5U5bON5g3GQ4RPjaG0OEOEhcZCfFLrwIqaimaePbk5bQIyyrjNILmL04NuBAA%3D)

при сборке с флагами /std:c++17 /permissive- /diagnostics:caret получаем

```
<source>(6,12): error C2975: 'x_address': invalid template argument for 'Foo', expected compile-time constant expression
Foo<bar + 4> b{};
           ^
<source>(1): note: see declaration of 'x_address'
template<auto x_address>
```

По стандарту параметр шаблона не-тип не может ссылаться на подобъект, которым является элемент массива:

> **[temp.arg.nontype]**
> 2 A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a converted constant expression (8.20) of the type of the template-parameter. For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, the value of the constant expression shall not refer to (or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of):
> — (2.1) a subobject (4.5),
> — (2.2) a temporary object (15.2),
> — (2.3) a string literal (5.13.5),
> — (2.4) the result of a typeid expression (8.2.8), or
> — (2.5) a predefined **func** variable (11.4.1).

> **[intro.object]**
> 2 Objects can contain other objects, called subobjects. A subobject can be a member subobject (12.2), a base class subobject (Clause 13), or an array element.

Что делать?
Передавать смещение от базового адреса в качестве еще одного параметра шаблона.